# How to register service in providers with dependencies?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have custom service `RequestsMethods` in Angular 5:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestsMethods {
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
  }
}
```

Where `HttpService` is:

```
import {Headers, Http, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

constructor(private router: Router, backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, options);
    }
}
```

My `ngModule` is:

```
providers: [
    BrowserXhr,
    XHRBackend,
    RequestsMethods,
    FormRegister
  ],
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RequestsMethods ->
>   HttpService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RequestsMethods
>   -> HttpService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpService!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.ge

From error message I got that I need register `HttpService` in providers, I tried:

```
providers: [
    HttpService,
    BrowserXhr,
    XHRBackend,
    RequestsMethods,
    FormRegister
  ],
```

Now I have another error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[XHRBackend -> ResponseOptions]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[XHRBackend -> ResponseOptions]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ResponseOptions!
```

Now my provider section is:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: RequestsMethods ,
      useFactory: RequestsMethodsFactory,
      deps: [HttpService]
    },
    FormRegister,
    ErrorWatcher,
    {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: httpFactoryService,
      deps: [Router, XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
  ],
```

**My last changes in ngModule file:**

```
export function httpFactoryService(router: Router, backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new HttpService(router, backend, options);
}

function RequestsMethodsFactory(router: Router, backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new RequestsMethods(httpFactoryService(router, backend, options));
}

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

providers: [
    {
      provide: RequestsMethods ,
      useFactory: RequestsMethodsFactory,
      deps: [Router, XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
    FormRegister,
    ErrorWatcher,
    {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: httpFactoryService,
      deps: [Router, XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: I have found solution, will post my answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function RequestsMethodsFactory(HttpService) {
    return new RequestsMethods(new HttpService());
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
....
  ],
  providers: [
   {
     provide: RequestsMethods ,
     useFactory: RequestsMethodsFactory,
     deps: [HttpService]
   },
   ....
],
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Read from the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers

Comment: Now I get this error: `ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpService -> XHRBackend]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpService -> XHRBackend]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for XHRBackend!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get`

Comment: please share your providers section now

Comment: Cause HttpService has also dependencies in constructor: `constructor(private router: Router, backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, options);
    }`

Comment: Updated question

Comment: See my question again please, I tried different way

Comment: `function httpServiceFactory(Router, XHRBackend, RequestOptions) {
    return new HttpService(new Router(), new HHRBackend(), new RequestOptions());
}`
You used the following method ?

Comment: Yes, can we move to chat?

Comment: It gives me `TypeError: Router is not a constructor`

Answer (score 1):

Your `HttpService` injects through the constructor three major tokens. Two of them (`XHRBackend` and `RequestOptions`) belong in the `HttpModule` (deprecated as for Angular 4.2 - you should use the types contained in `HttpClientModule` instead). The other one is `Router`, which belongs in `RouterModule`.

In order for your Ngmodule to be aware of the types and tokens required in the cnstructor, you will want to declare both `RouterModule` and `HttpModule` in the `imports` property of your `Ngmodule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,  // <-- This!
    HttpModule     // <-- And this!
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpService,
    RequestsMethods,

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I got message that `HttpModule` deprecated too

Comment: Sorry, I meant “you should use the types contained in HttpClientModule instead” @OPV